# Send command over a mapped port via kubernetes service

Tags: networking, kubernetes, port

I have an application that can receive commands from a specific port like so:

```
echo <command> | nc <hostname> <port>
```

In this case it is opening port 22082, I believe in it's Docker container.

When I place this application into a kubernetes pod, I need to expose it by creating a kubernetes service. Here is my service:

```
 apiVersion: v1                                                                                                                                                                            
 kind: Service                                                                                                                
 metadata:                                                                                                                    
  name: commander                                                                                                            
 spec:                                                                                                                        
   selector:                                                                                                                  
     app: commander                                                                                                           
   ports:                                                                                                                     
     - protocol: TCP                                                                                                          
       port: 22282                                                                                                            
       targetPort: 22082                                                                                                      
   #type: NodePort                                                                                                            
   externalIPs:                                                                                                               
   -  10.10.30.19
```

NOTE: I commented out NodePort because I haven't been able to expose the port using that method. Whenever I use `sudo netstat -nlp | grep 22282` I get nothing.

Using an external IP i'm able to find the port and connect to it using netcat, but whenever I issue a command over the port, it just hangs.

Normally I should be able to issue a 'help' command and get information on the app. With kubernetes I can't get that same output.

Now, if I use `hostNetwork: true` in my app yaml (not the service), I can connect to the port **and** get my 'help' info.

What could be keeping my command from reaching the app while not using hostNetwork configuration?

Thanks

UPDATE: Noticed this message from `sudo iptables --list`:

```
Chain KUBE-SERVICES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.21.155.23        /* default/commander: has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:22282 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

UPDATE #2: I solved the above error by setting spec.template.metadata.labels.app to commander. I still, however, am experiencing an inability to send any command to the app.

Comment: If you use NodePort, you will gave more grater than 30000, using that port you should able to connect to pod. Here is mine `NAME                                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
grafana-grafana                            NodePort    10.104.97.35     <none>        80:30612/TCP     17d
`

Comment: @sfgroups So you're saying I need to set my `port` field to a value greater than 30000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @sfgroups I discovered that I needed to set an actual `nodePort` like so:

```
apiVersion: v1                                                                                                                                                                            
 kind: Service                                                                                                                
 metadata:                                                                                                                    
  name: commander                                                                                                            
 spec:                                                                                                                        
   selector:                                                                                                                  
     app: commander                                                                                                           
   ports:                                                                                                                     
     - protocol: TCP                                                                                                          
       port: 22282
       nodePort: 32282                                                                                                            
       targetPort: 22082                                                                                                      
   type: NodePort
```

Pretty odd behavior, makes me wonder what the point of the `port` field even is!

Comment: The port field makes more sense when accessing the service inside the cluster (i.e. a pod that accesses the service). It would have to use port 22282 in that case

Comment: @JavierSalmeron Oh I see so it's all about scope of the port. Thanks